# Laravel 4 change name of root "laravel" folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to change the "laravel" main folder which contains the app, public, vendor, etc folder to "project_name" but when I just rename the folder, laravel does not open (seems like a 500 error or something) when I install laravel straight into the "project_name" with composer it works, but I feel like there needs to be a way to change the folder name afterwards. What do I have to do so it works?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to change the folder name every once in a while?

Comment: Well, I might want to change it, because of whatever, lets say a typo or so. I tend to change them, like if I rebuild a website I keep the old one and the new one is named "website_new" but later I want to change it to "website"

Comment: I guess you could change it any time, but do a dump-autoload every time you change it. It should be fine.

Comment: Sadly it does not work, I get a "Server error" in chrome. I renamed it and ran artisan dump-autoload as well as composer dump-autoload. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm sounds strange. What is the URL you tried to open?

Comment: www/vr/public does not work www/laravel/public does before the renaming of the folder (laravel -> vr)

Comment: This is strange. I will try to rename one of my own projects and let you know if it went through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so actually it works, all you really have to do, is restart php after renaming it (which works fine locally). I do not know why, though, since other php apps don't need it.